# ffmpeg move overlay from x1 to x2 with 3 sec duration

Tags: ffmpeg

how to move overlay from `x1` to `x2` between `00:00:05-00:00:08` seconds and again move from `x2` to `x1` between `00:00:17-00:00:20` seconds using [Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Expression-Evaluation) ?

`[bg][fg]overlay= {??????} : 230`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
x='X1+(X2-X1)*(between(t,5,8)*(t-5)/3+between(t,8,17)-between(t,17,20)*(t-20)/3)'
```